# not able to notarize electron app using forge

Tags: electron, electron-forge

hello I am building electron app for the mac platform and having trouble notarize the app using Forge and getting this error:

**Packaging ApplicationWARNING: Code sign failed; please retry manually. Error: Command failed: spctl --assess --type execute --verbose --ignore-cache --no-cache /var/folders/q7/*****/T/electron-packager/darwin-arm64/Integration-darwin-arm64/Integration.app
/var/folders/q7/******/T/electron-packager/darwin-arm64/Integration-darwin-arm64/Integration.app: rejected
source=Unnotarized Developer ID**

my forge config

```
"forge": {
      "packagerConfig": {
        "appBundleId": "com.anyfolder.integrations",
        "osxSign": {
          "identity": "Developer ID Application: ****** (****)",
          "hardened-runtime": true,
          "entitlements": "entitlements.plist",
          "entitlements-inherit": "entitlements.plist",
          "signature-flags": "library"
        },
        "osxNotarize": {
          "appleId": "myid@id.com",
          "appleIdPassword": "my-password"
        },
        "protocols": [
          {
            "name": "Any Folder",
            "schemes": [
              "electron-****"
            ]
          }
        ],
      
        "icon": "public/images/icon.ico"
      },
      "publishers": [
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/publisher-s3",
          "config": {
            "bucket": "*******",
            "folder": "integrations",
            "public": true
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/publisher-github",
          "config": {
            "repository": {
              "owner": "****",
              "name": "****"
            },
            "draft": false,
            "prerelease": false
          }
        }
      ],
      "makers": [
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel",
          "config": {
            "name": "integrations"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-dmg",
          "config": {
            "icon": "public/images/icon.icns",
            "format": "ULFO",
            "name": "Name",
            "overwrite": true,
            "debug": true
          }
        }
      ],
      "plugins": [
        [
          "@electron-forge/plugin-webpack",
          {
            "mainConfig": "./webpack.main.config.js",
            "renderer": {
              "config": "./webpack.renderer.config.js",
              "entryPoints": [
                {
                  "html": "./src/render/imageEditor/index.html",
                  "js": "./src/render/imageEditor/index.tsx",
                  "name": "capture_window",
                  "preload": {
                    "js": "./src/render/imageEditor/preload.ts"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "name": "main_window",
                  "html": "./src/index.html",
                  "js": "./src/render/main/index.tsx",
                  "preload": {
                    "js": "./src/render/main/preload.ts"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "name": "integrations_menu",
                  "html": "./src/index.html",
                  "js": "./src/render/integrations/index.tsx",
                  "preload": {
                    "js": "./src/render/integrations/preload.ts"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
```